# how to overwrite ionic background color?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a mobile app using angularjs and ionic.iconic default color is white.I need to change my app background color to blue without changing ionic css.so I manually set default color to index.html like

```
body { background-color:azure !important; }
```

but still background color is white.how to manage this without changing ionic.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use .scroll-content {
    background-color:azure !important;(change background color here)
}

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding *pane* class in your custom css file.

```
.pane{
  background-color: azure;
}
```